# Can we have a "no answers" top button?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, unanswered-questions

The Unanswered button currently shows all questions with no accepted answers and no upvoted answers.

I suggest bifurcating this functionality into two buttons: one with the current functionality, the other with a list of questions that have no answer attempts at all.

A few badges for answering (and getting upvotes) for very old un-answered questions would be a nice complement to this feature.

I realize that button space across the top is precious, so there may be some resistance to this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answers to old questions? And getting upvoted? You could qualify for [a Necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer).

As for combing through questions with no answers at all, click on the <kbd>[No Answers At All](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0)</kbd> button.

Answer (score 2):

This has been implemented (or re-implemented, if @Brad's comment is correct). The Unanswered list now has a "no answers" sort option.

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers